# Select2 ajax does nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2

I'm having an issue with the select2 (4.0.3) ajax call for the "type ahead" function.
I originally had this as an input then changed it to a select to support the 4.0 requirement. Everything I have should be working based on the documentation. What am I missing?
I appreciate a second set of eyes. Thanks for your help.

my code...

HTML

```
<select 
  id="medList2" 
  placeholder="Drug" 
  class="select2" 
  style="width: 200px;" 
  data-sequence="80" 
  data-parent-id="4" 
  data-id="80" 
  data-label="Drugs" 
  data-bind-0="4-80"></select>
```

Javascript

```
$('#medList2').select2({     
        ajax: {              
            url: '/path/todata/',
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            type: "POST",
            // id: getUnid(),
           // contentType: "application/json",
            data: function (term) {                   
                return {
                    Prefix: term
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data) {                  
                return {
                    results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            text: item.Text,
                            id: item.ID

                        }
                    })
                };
            },
            cache: true
        },
        placeholder: 'Choose Meds',
        minimumInputLength: 2           

    });
```

Comment: Have you added the `select2` init inside a `$(document).ready(function(){ })`. What errors do you see in the console?

Comment: Yes.. The odd thing is that it doesn't do anything at all. no error. I walked through the select2 init. and it goes through with no errors